# Div not expanding with content, not clearing other elements

Tags: html, css

I have a need for text to be displayed in some bounding boxes, the content may vary, and I need the boxes to expand to encompass the content with regards to screen size. I also need the multiple boxes to NOT collide with one another.

Here is a js fiddle example of my problem - I have tried 
overflow: auto - this resulted in a scroll box (not acceptable)
clear:both - in various locations - this results in no change

The goal can be seen in the top yellow box, to have a minimum box size...
but the problem comes if (1) the content is larger than the space OR (2) if the space shrinks...as in a smaller screen

I am clearly missing something

https://jsfiddle.net/grfap4o5/

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.stack-top {
  z-index: 9;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background: gold;"></div>
  <div class="box stack-top" style="background: grey;">
    <p>This is a title</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph - The goal - to maintain the grey border - offset... regardless of amount of text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background: red;"></div>
  <div class="box stack-top" style="background: grey;">
    <p>This is a title</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes</p>

    <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background: blue;"></div>
  <div class="box stack-top" style="background: grey;">
    <p>This is a title</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes</p>

    <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your boxes to relative positioning.

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

This allows the container to realize you have content inside of it and it will stretch to the size of the box.

Without scrolling, you will have to change the size of the font to fit the screen when screen size is too small.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve. You can use a pseudo `before` (or `after`) to create the box and then use an inner div that has the background and a z-index to place it above the colored square.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 20px 40px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.inner {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>This is a title</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph - The goal - to maintain the grey border - offset... regardless of amount of text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>This is a title</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes</p>

      <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>This is a title</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes</p>

      <p>This is a paragraph - it has significant content, length Trying to mimic what is happening in real site - but isolated for demonstration purposes
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you see your grey boxes got pushed behind the yellow..?
I'll play with it

Comment: They didn't. It's because of the opacity of the gray box over the yellow. I made it darker in the snippet so you could see.